# How to copy entire row without error caused by empty cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy entire row, but the problem is if there is any empty cell of first or last row, the line of `myRange.Copy` gives an error message "That command cannot be used on multiple selections"

```
Sub SaveLastLine()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim myRange As Range

    'copy the content
        Set myRange = Union(Range(Range("B1:B3"), Range("B1:B3").End(xlToRight)), _
                            Range(Range("B1").End(xlDown), Range("B1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)))
        myRange.Copy

    'paste the content
        Set WB = Workbooks.Add
        WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

How can I copy my rows even if there are some empty cells?

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822225/copy-non-blank-cells-from-range-to-range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Range setting so it pulls the whole row for all rows in the range:

```
Dim myRange
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B3")
myRange.EntireRow.Copy
```

Then it'll PasteSpecial correctly into the new workbook